# Excel - Drag to right in Sheet 1 with left direction reference in Sheet 2

Tags: excel

How I can make Cell B3 in Sheet 1 to the right direction, but with the opposite-directed reference in Sheet 2 ?

[image]

I have used Google to research my question, but I did not get anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understand your question but if you want to enter the data in reverse order based on the picture on the right,

you can use hlookup if the data is not duplicated

```
B3 = HLOOKUP (B2,Sheet2!$J$2:$L$3,2,0)
```

or

```
B3 = OFFSET (Sheet2!$L$3,, - 1 * COLUMN (A1) +1)
```

Comment: Have in mind that data is in different sheets. So, formulas would have to be adjusted

Comment: @The GridLock Thank you thank you, love you guys genius ~~~~.

Comment: Thank you thank you, love you guys genius @ Ricardo Diaz